# ESLint in Vue : Missing space before function parentheses

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, eslint

I created a project with npm and vuejs/vue-cli.
I have eslint entries in my package.json file.

I got a warning when running my code :

> WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings
>   5:57:37 AM
>
> ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren  Missing
>   space before function parentheses   src/components/HomePage.vue:142:9
>         show() {
>              ^
>
> ✘ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

what should i do with the space in this line?

```
export default {
  el: '#skills',
  props: {
    skill: Object,
    selectedId: Number
  },
  computed: {
    show() { //in this line
      return this.skill.id === this.selectedId
    }
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, you're missing a space after your function name and before your parenthesis:

> Missing space before function parentheses

There is an ESLint rule in your code that states your function must be formatted like so:

`myFunction () { ... }`

You have your function formatted like so:

`myFunction() { ... }`

If you add a space between `show` and `()` it should resolve the issue. Here's the correct snippet:

```
export default {
  el: '#skills',
  props: {
    skill: Object,
    selectedId: Number
  },
  computed: {
    show () { //in this line
      return this.skill.id === this.selectedId
    }
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You may either add the space before the paren or (preferred option) update your `.eslintrc.js` file to represent your style preferences.

I recommend you add this rule in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
rules: {
  'space-before-function-paren': ['error', {
    anonymous: 'always',
    named: 'never',
    asyncArrow: 'always'
  }]
}
```

The Docs:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren#require-or-disallow-a-space-before-function-parenthesis-space-before-function-paren

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js` to `prettier-eslint`.

If you're using TypeScript, you may need to set `vetur.format.defaultFormatter.ts` to `prettier-tslint` instead.

[image]

Comment: For me, using `vscode-javascript` and `vscode-typescript` worked best.

Comment: BIG THANKS FOR THIS ANSWER ;)

Answer (score 0):

If we are using anonymous function then it is showing error. To solve this use arrow function.